# Are generics parameterized by values the same as dependent types?

Tags: generics, language-agnostic, dependent-type

I've been reading up on dependent types and I have one question to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something. The [Wikipedia page on dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) starts with this:

> In computer science and logic, a dependent type is a type whose definition depends on a value. A "pair of integers" is a type. A "pair of integers where the second is greater than the first" is a dependent type because of the dependence on the value.

---

Suppose I have a language where I can represent a number in a range:

```
struct Int<Min, Max>
```

For example, the type `Int<0, 10>` represents an integer between 0 inclusive and 10 exclusive.

As a bonus, suppose I introduce generic variance:

```
struct Int<in Min, out Max>
```

For example, instances of types such as `Int<3, 10>` and `Int<0, 8>` can be assigned to variables of type `Int<0, 10>`.

Now the addition operation on this type could have a signature like this:

```
Int<Min1 + Min2, Max1 + Max2> operator+(Int<Min1, Max1> op1, Int<Min2, Max2> op2);
```

So, adding an `Int<0, 10>` and an `Int<3, 4>` would produce a result of type `Int<3, 14>`.

In such a type system, we could also have ordered pairs, such as:

```
struct OrderedPair<Min, Mid, Max>
{
    Int<Min, Mid> SmallerNumber;
    Int<Mid, Max> LargerNumber;
}
```

And so on.

---

Is this different from dependent typing? If so, how?

Comment: A dependent type allows you to attach a predicate to a type, and check that it holds in all operations. If you can limit your system to a few predicates (like min/max for a range), you can offload it to type parameters to a degree; Haskell sort of allows to do that, I heard. That is, for a practical case of numbers within a range or lists of no more than N elements, you can probably achieve that. In general case, likely not, else why would people invent dependently-typed languages?

Comment: @9000 Yeah, I am basically trying to understand whether certain types (such as this `Int<Min, Max>`, a possible `List<T, Size>`, as well as a few others), can basically be used as building blocks to arrive at an entire type system of dependent types, or a dependent type system is something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limited form of dependent typing, in which types can depend on values, but those values must be available at compile time.

In a fully dependently typed language such as [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/), types can also depend on runtime values—in order to construct such a value, you need a [proof](http://dafoster.net/articles/2015/02/27/proof-terms-in-idris/) in scope that the value inhabits the type. One way to obtain a proof is with a simple test (pseudocode):

```
m = user_input();
n = user_input();

// Type error: n is not guaranteed to be in range.
x = Int<0, m>(n);

if (n >= 0 && n <= m) {
  // Accepted: proofs of n >= 0 and n <= m in scope.
  x = Int<0, m>(n);
}
```

So you can implement your example in (say) C++, but constructing an `Int<Min, Max>` requires a dynamic check in the constructor; if C++ had full dependent types, you couldn’t even *call* the constructor without some form of check (static or dynamic).

Comment: The part about the proof being required in order to create instances makes sense to me. However, in this code, `m` is a runtime value. It's not just that we went from `n` (an unrestricted `int`, presumably) to an `Int<0, m>`, that part I understand. But `Int<0, m>` contains a value that's not known statically. Can the enclosing function return `x` then? Can the type of the enclosing function be `Int<0, m>`? If so, when I attempt to assign `Int<0, m>` to `Int<0, 5>`, how will the compiler know if I'm going to a more or a less specific type?

Comment: The type of `x` in that if-statement is `Int<0, m>`, but the type of the enclosing function cannot be that, because it's not known (can't be proven) that the runtime values will pass this if-check. However, if you have an else-clause which returns `0` (or `m`), than you can derive that the return type of the whole thing is `Int<0, m>`.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: I think you could return the value by wrapping it in an existential, `∃m. Int<0, m>`, then the caller could unpack it to work with the value of `m` locally. That is, the function says “I return a value in the range [0, *m*] for some *m*”. An existential type is called a “dependent pair” or “sigma type” in this context, because it’s a pair of a value `m` and a type `Int<0, m>` that depends on it.